# Trying to animate shapes in canvas, it shows up, but doesn't move

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to animate polygons made using `lineTo` in canvas. It shows up, but won't move. I tried to follow the object approach, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Help?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
            canvas {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            </style>
            <script>
            "use strict";
            var canvas;
            var ctx;
            var timer;
            var shapes;
            var x;
            var y;
            function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
                    return (degrees*Math.PI)/180;
                }
    //to rotate stuff, not currently in use
            function rotateStuff() {
            roTimer = setInterval(ctx.rotate(degreesToRadians(60)),100); 
            }
    //constructor for Shape object, not currently in use
            function Shape() {
            //this.x = canvas.width/2 + Math.random()*10-5;
            //this.y = canvas.height/2 + Math.random()*10-5;
            this.r = Math.random()*20-5;
            this.vx = Math.random()*10-5;
            this.vy = Math.random()*10-5;
            var colors = ['red','green','orange','purple','blue','aqua','pink','gold'];
            this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            }
    //pushes the shapes to an array, not currently in use
            function makeShapes() {
                shapes = [];
                for (var i = 0; i<2; i++){
                    shapes.push(new Shape());
                    }
            }
    //fills and resets background
            function fillBackground() {
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
            }
    //draws the shape
            function drawShapes(r, p, m) {
            //canvas, x position, y position, radius, number of points, fraction of radius for inset
            fillBackground();
            x = 350;
            y = 350;
            r = Math.random()*20-5;
                //for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                    //var s = shapes[i];
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.translate(x, y);
                    ctx.moveTo(0,0-r);
                    //}
                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < p; i2++) {
                    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / p);
                    ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - (r*m));
                    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / p);
                    ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - r);
                }
                ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
                ctx.fill();

                var vx = Math.random()*10-5;
                var vy = Math.random()*10-5;
                x += vx;
                y += vy;
                r -=8
                ctx.restore();
            }
            //}
            window.onload = function() {

                    canvas = document.getElementById('animCanvas');
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    //makeShapes();
                    //console.log(shapes);
                    timer = setInterval(drawShapes(40, 5, 0.5), 100);
                    //timer2 = setInterval(makeShapes, 4500);

                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas width='700' height='700' id='animCanvas'></canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A coding hint:** Separate your code into discrete duties. This separation lets you concentrate your coding focus on simpler tasks. And once you've got that task running correctly you can move onto another task without worrying that a previous task has become broken.

**Here are the tasks for your "rotate stars" project**

```
1. Draw a star and 
2. Rotate that star using animation.*
```

... and their  descriptions

**`drawShapes()`** draws one star at a specified `[x,y]` position at a specified `currentAngle`

**`animate()`** runs an animation loop that:

```
  Clears the canvas.
  Fills the background.
  Draws the star (or many stars) with `drawShapes`.
  Changes the `currentAngle` rotation for the next loop.
  Requests another animation loop.
```

**About rotating**

Rotating your shape is a simple 2 step process:

```
1. Move to the shape's centerpoint: `.translate(centerX,centerY)'
2. Rotate the canvas to the currently desired angle: `rotate(currentAngle)`
```

Since `translate` and `rotate` are not automatically undone, you must "clean up" after your transformations. An easy way to do that is to do this: `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`. This sets the internal transformation matrix to its default state (==fully untransformed).

So your rotation process becomes:

```
1. Move to the shape's centerpoint: `.translate(centerX,centerY)'
2. Rotate the canvas to the currently desired angle: `.rotate(currentAngle)`
3. Reset the canvas: `.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`
```

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;

canvas = document.getElementById('animCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var shapes=[];
var star1={ x:50, y:100, r:40, currentAngle:0, p:5, m:.5, fill:'yellow',angleChange:Math.PI/60}
var star2={ x:150, y:100, r:25, currentAngle:0, p:55, m:5, fill:'blue',angleChange:-Math.PI/360}
var star3={ x:250, y:100, r:25, currentAngle:0, p:15, m:3, fill:'red',angleChange:Math.PI/120}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function drawShapes(star) {
    ctx.save();
    // translate to the star's centerpoint
    ctx.translate(star.x,star.y);
    // rotate to the current angle
    ctx.rotate(star.currentAngle)
    // draw the star
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0-star.r);
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < star.p; i2++) {
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / star.p);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - (star.r*star.m));
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / star.p);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - star.r);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle =star.fill;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function fillBackground() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
}

function animate(time){
    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // fill the background
    fillBackground();

    // draw the stars
    // If you put star1,star2,star3 in a stars[] array then
    //     you could simply the following demo code by looping
    //     through the array
    //
    // draw the star1
    drawShapes(star1);
    // increase star1's current rotation angle
    star1.currentAngle+=star1.angleChange;
    // draw the star2
    drawShapes(star2);
    // increase star2's current rotation angle
    star2.currentAngle+=star2.angleChange;
    // draw the star3
    drawShapes(star3);
    // increase star3's current rotation angle
    star3.currentAngle+=star2.angleChange;
    // request another animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<canvas width='700' height='700' id='animCanvas'></canvas>    </body>
```